# SOLID design principles, GUI and Model abstraction

Tags: c#, design-patterns, abstraction, solid-principles

I have a data structure like so

League --< Rounds ---< Games ---2 Players

However, when a round is created it needs to know what Pairing method is chosen on the GUI, prior to creation, so it knows how to pair the teams.

Can anyone over advice on how to implement this? 
I want to keep the model seperate from the GUI but I can't create a round object without knowing the selected Pairing method. 
And I am not sure what the best way to implement the pairings is.

I've thought something like

```
interface IPairingMethod{}
public class RoundRobin:IPairingMethod{}
```

And use DI in the Round constructor but it doesnt seem clean. Would the factory pattern help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 3):

From my perspective a factory method or even an abstract factory sound like a solution for your problem. In case you don't want to dynamically change the pairing method during runtime you could also think about using an IoC container.